# Principal diagonals of octagon meet in a single point

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, elementary-proofs, polygons

Can you provide a proof for the following claim:

> **Claim.** Given octagon circumscribed about an ellipse. If the vertices of the octagon lie on another ellipse then its principal diagonals meet in a single point.

[image]

The GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/rhez3jat).

Comment: A short proof is as follows:  Consider the two ellipses, since there is one octagon inscribed in one and circumscribed about the other, it follows from Poncelet's Theorem that there is a circle of such octagons. Moreover, when one chooses (projective) coordinates so that the inner ellipse $E_1$ is $x^2+y^2=1$ and the outer ellipse $E_2$ is $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, by symmetry of the 'translation map', the opposite vertex of the octagon passing through $(x,y)\in E_2$ is $(-x,-y)$, so the line joining them passes through $(0,0)$. QED

Comment: By the way, note that the above proof works for any $2m$-gon $P$ that is circumscribed about an ellipse $E_1$ and inscribed in another ellipse $E_2$:  The $m$ lines joining opposite pairs of vertices are of $P$ are concurrent.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thanks.